# Sharepoint 2010 event reciever item adding

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

is it possible to retrieve the "Modified" date column in item adding event reciever?

Comment: DateTime.Now() will be close to the correct value ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, that field is null at this time.

Comment: Please could you expand on this a little? - very short answers like this, while technically correct, get flagged up by the system. +1 for good answer though :-)